# unable to make non-stationary turtles change their direction if an obstacle a patch ahead

Tags: netlogo

If any one please give some time.

I have an area(say a colony) with boundary wall as black patches and at some point within the boundary there is one building with building wall as blue patches. People(breed) are normally moving inside boundary and the building as well. Also they are entering and going out of the boundary. Due to some reason (suppose rumor) and after certain condition (if more than 15 person hears the rumor) they starts moving randomly with any of the headings 0, 90, 180 and 270. So, the problem I am unable is, to apply check on the turtles(people) randomly moving to change their heading or turn back if they sense the boundary or wall a patch ahead.

I tried following ways but not working, they simple passes form these patches
1)  Asked the turtles if heard-rumor? and times-heard > 1 [
      if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = blue [set heading [heading] of self - 180]
      if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black [set heading [heading] of self - 180]                      ]

2)  set patches with boundary-wall [set pcolor black] and building-wall [set pcolor blue] and then set  patch variables boundary-wall? And building-wall?  true on these patches. Further asked the turtles 
    if heard-rumor? and times-heard > 1 [
        if boundary-wall? or building-wall? [ set heading [heading] of self -  180 ] ]

The procedure sequence is

```
to go
    ask people [ ;breed
    fd speed
    spread-rumor
    people-wander ]
end
```

So after spread-rumor function,

```
 to people-wander
    if heard-rumor? and times-heard > 1 and inside-boundary?
    [ 
        if people-heard-rumor > 10 [ set heading one-of (list 0 90 180 270)     ]  ];random 360 
      ;people-heard-rumor is a count how many have received rumor

        if heard-rumor? or fear-worst? [
         ; if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = blue [set heading [heading] of self - 180]]          
         ; if [pcolor] of patch-ahead 1 = black [set heading [heading] of self - 180]]

  boundary-wall? or temple-wall? [set i? true set heading [heading] of self - 180 show 5] ]

end
```

I don’t know what wrong I am doing. But surely I am not using proper way. Any help is deeply thankful.

Answer (score 2):

You start out with `fd speed` so your `people` will go right through the barriers on that command without ever testing for a barrier.  Note that even if you were to test 1 patch ahead before doing that, if `speed` can be greater than 1, you could still go right through the barriers. Furthermore, in a corner a `person` might have a barrier both in front of it and behind it, so reversing course can also be a problem.

Btw, `[heading] of self` is the same as `heading`, and to turn around it is more natural to say `rt 180`.

**EDIT (in response to comment):**

Here is a simple example of moving step by step, checking along the way:

```
to fd-with-checks [#speed]
  repeat #speed [
    ifelse (isbarrier? patch-ahead 1) [
      stop
    ] [
      fd 1
    ]
  ]
end

to-report isbarrier? [#patch]
  report pcolor = blue or pcolor = black
end
```

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks.... And that you mean fd speed should always be used after implementing the things that I want to ask from turtles...

Comment: If you want to `fd speed` when there might be barriers. you need to first check that there are no barriers in the way.  So you cannot just test `patch-ahead 1`; you need to check all the intervening patches.  One strategy is to go forward a step at a time, each time checking the `patch-ahead 1` and stopping if it's a barrier.  But even this will allow a person to "run over" the corner of a barrier.

Comment: I am sorry but i didn't got you, "to go forward a step at a time each time checking the patch-ahead 1 and stopping". Can you please show with example. Thanks.