# Can we code to calculate the difference of tick values in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

Actually i need to calculate density increase/decrease rate of human population for my model, the model is same as i asked in [unable to make non-stationary turtles change their direction if an obstacle a patch ahead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31803310/unable-to-make-non-stationary-turtles-change-their-direction-if-an-obstacle-a-pa) (a specific area and a building within it, people are randomly visiting and going). What i thought that i will be needing to save the tick values for initial population value and after some time difference updated population value. Below is the procedure i want to plot graph for.

```
to density-increase-rate

  store population-density at some initial time (ticks)
  store updated-population-density at some later-time (ticks)

  calculate density-increase-rate

   ( ( ( updated-pd - previous-pd ) / (updated-tick - previous-tick ) ) * 100   ) / 10

  end
```

I am calculating population-density in my code as

```
total-density-inside-boundary count people with [inside-boundary?]
```

for any suggestion or code help i am very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to plot this change, there is no need to store it because the plot will update each tick.

```
globals [total-density-inside-boundary density-increase-rate]

to calc-plot-vars
  let old-density total-density-inside-boundary
  set total-density-inside-boundary count people with [inside-boundary?]
  set density-increase-rate (total-density-inside-boundary - old-density) / 100
end
```

Then have a plot on the interface with `plot total-density-inside-boundary` and `plot density-increase-rate`. You may need to do some rescaling to have them both on the same plot.

If you want to have the rate based on total time, then create a variable to hold the initial value and calculate it at the specific time you think initial means (such as the end of the setup or at a specific tick).

```
globals [total-density-inside-boundary initial-density]

to setup
  ... (commands that create your people)
  set initial-density count people with [inside-boundary?]
  ...
end

to go
  ...
  if ticks = 1 [ set initial-density count people with [inside-boundary?] ]
  ...
end
```

Then have the rate plot in the interface have `plot (total-density-inside-boundary - initial-density) / 100`

Comment: Thank you sir. I understood the second part of the code to calculate rate and to plot it. Since the formula i knew to calculate density rate  is (updated-density - initial-density / time-duration) * 100 , so i was stuck with time-duration part that how to find time difference (like 100ticks - 10ticks).

Comment: And the first part you said to do let old-density total-density-inside-boundary
set total-density-inside-boundary count people with [inside-boundary?]  so here, will the value of this local variable "old-density" remains static even the values of total-density-inside-boundary gets updated

Comment: No, old-density will change each tick, so the first version will give plot the change between one tick and the next. If you want the plot to be the average rate from some arbitrary tick (like the start) until "now" then use the second version.

Comment: Sir for average rate i am getting (-)ve values too. My model stops at 1000 ticks and i took initial tick value 200( instead of tick = 1). so after some time it gives (-)ve values. but i think this will be wrong.

Comment: Look at the plot of total-density-inside-boundary. Does it decrease after ticks = 200? If so, the rate is actually negative and not an error.

Comment: and the other thing its happening when exits are more than entries, so is there any way that we can do for that...

Comment: yes sir its the same as you said. so we can skip this part in our results.